Asking for a single file database engine replacement of BDE
I use BDE that is deprecated and I want to migrate to another DB engine that does not work in client-server mode but it must access its database locally or remotely as a single file like BDE or Absolute Database. Any suggestions please?

What's your IDE? Have you looked at Firebird?
